# How do I create multiple levels in pygame?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, 2d-games

I can't get my "world_data2" and "world_data3" to draw to the screen. only the "world_data" at index position 0 of the "levels" list draws. Everything else seems to be working. The bats and the doors change in every level, but the tile layout stays exactly the same. Is it possibly something to do with my "reset_level" function? or my world class?

Improved code:

```
# Importing the pygame library
import pygame

# Initializing pygame
pygame.init()

# Clock and frame rate
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60

# Creating the game window
screen_width = 1500
screen_height = 1000

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

# Setting game window caption
pygame.display.set_caption('Castle Escape')

# Define game variables
tile_size = 50
game_over = 0
main_menu = True
current_level_index = 0
total_levels = 2

# Loading images
background_img = pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/purplebackground.jpg')
restart_img = pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Buttons/restart.png')
restart_img = pygame.transform.scale(restart_img, (80, 40))
play_img = pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Buttons/play.png')
play_img = pygame.transform.scale(play_img, (350, 190))
exit_img = pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Buttons/exit.png')
exit_img = pygame.transform.scale(exit_img, (350, 190))
controls_img = pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Buttons/controls.png')
controls_img = pygame.transform.scale(controls_img, (350, 190))
settings_img = pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Buttons/settings.png')
settings_img = pygame.transform.scale(settings_img, (350, 190))
menu_img = pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Buttons/menu.png')
menu_img = pygame.transform.scale(menu_img, (80, 40))

# Instances for groups
bat_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
door_group = pygame.sprite.Group()


# Function to draw grid
def draw_grid():
    for line in range(0, 30):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (0, line * tile_size), (screen_width, line * tile_size))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (line * tile_size, 0), (line * tile_size, screen_height))


# Function to reset levels
def reset_level(current_level_index):
    # Reset player position
    player.reset(100, screen_height - 130)
    # Empty groups
    bat_group.empty()
    door_group.empty()
    # Load in level data and create world
    if current_level_index <= total_levels:
        level = levels[current_level_index]
        world = World(level)

    return world


# Class for world map
class World:
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, data):
        # List to store locations of tiles
        self.tile_list = []

        # Load images
        ground_img = pygame.image.load('Assets/Medieval Tileset/PNG/Tiles/tile59.png')
        ground2_img = pygame.image.load('Assets/Medieval Tileset/PNG/Tiles/tile34.png')
        leftwall_img = pygame.image.load('Assets/Medieval Tileset/PNG/Tiles/tile56.png')
        rightwall_img = pygame.image.load('Assets/Medieval Tileset/PNG/Tiles/tile58.png')
        ceiling_img = pygame.image.load('Assets/Medieval Tileset/PNG/Tiles/tile146.png')

        # Loop to run through each row of world grid
        row_count = 0
        for row in data:
            # Loop to run through each column in each row of world grid
            col_count = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1:
                    # Scale images to 50 x 50px
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(ground_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    # Take rectangle
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    # x and y coordinates for rectangle
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                if tile == 2:
                    # Scale images to 50 x 50px
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(leftwall_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    # Take rectangle
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    # x and y coordinates for rectangle
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                if tile == 3:
                    # Scale images to 50 x 50px
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(rightwall_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    # Take rectangle
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    # x and y coordinates for rectangle
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                if tile == 4:
                    # Scale images to 50 x 50px
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(ceiling_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    # Take rectangle
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    # x and y coordinates for rectangle
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                if tile == 5:
                    # Scale images to 50 x 50px
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(ground2_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    # Take rectangle
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    # x and y coordinates for rectangle
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                if tile == 6:
                    # Create instance of bat enemy
                    bat = Enemy(col_count * tile_size, row_count * tile_size)
                    bat_group.add(bat)
                if tile == 7:
                    # Create instance of door
                    door = Doors(col_count * tile_size, row_count * tile_size - 50)
                    door_group.add(door)
                col_count += 1
            row_count += 1

    # Method to draw tiles to screen
    def drawWorld(self):
        # Loop to iterate through tile_list
        for tile in self.tile_list:
            screen.blit(tile[0], tile[1])
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), tile[1], 2)


# Class for buttons
class Button:
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        self.image = image
        # Create rectangle
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        # Check whether mouse click occurs
        self.clicked = False

    # Draw method
    def draw(self):
        # Variable holds whether restart button been clicked or not
        action = False

        # Get mouse position
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # Check mouseover and clicked conditions
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                self.clicked = True
                action = True

        # Make sure button can only be clicked once
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
            self.clicked = False

        # Draw button
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

        return action


# Class for player (sprite)
class Player:
    # Spawn Player
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Call reset method
        self.reset(x, y)

    def updatePlayer(self, game_over):
        dx = 0  # move along x
        dy = 0  # move along y
        run_slowDown = 5  # Slow down run animation

        if game_over == 0:

            # Key controls
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            # Move player left
            if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                dx -= 3
                self.counter += 1
                self.direction = -1

            # Move player right
            if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                dx += 3
                self.counter += 1
                self.direction = 1

            # Show idle image if no keys are being pressed
            if key[pygame.K_LEFT] == False and key[pygame.K_RIGHT] == False:
                self.counter = 0
                self.index = 0
                if self.direction == 0 or self.direction == 1:
                    self.image = pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Warrior/Idle/idle1.png')
                    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (60, 90))
                if self.direction == -1:
                    self.image = pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Warrior/Idle/idle1.png')
                    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (60, 90))
                    self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)

            # Make player jump
            self.rect.y += self.vel_y
            if key[pygame.K_SPACE] and self.jumped == False and self.in_air == False:
                self.vel_y = -12
                self.jumped = True
            if not key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                self.jumped = False

            # Handle animations
            if self.counter > run_slowDown:
                self.counter = 0
                self.index += 1
                if self.index >= len(self.transformed_rightRun):
                    self.index = 0
                if self.direction == 1:
                    self.image = self.transformed_rightRun[self.index]
                if self.direction == -1:
                    self.image = self.images_leftRun[self.index]

            # Add gravity
            self.vel_y += 1
            # Add terminal velocity
            if self.vel_y > 2:
                self.vel_y = 2
            dy += self.vel_y

            # Check for collision with tiles
            self.in_air = True
            for tile in world.tile_list:
                # Check for collision in x-direction
                if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.x + dx, self.rect.y, self.width, self.height):
                    dx = 0
                # Check for collision in y-direction
                if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.x, self.rect.y + dy, self.width, self.height):
                    # Check if hitting head on tile (jumping)
                    if self.vel_y < 0:
                        dy = tile[1].bottom - self.rect.top
                        self.vel_y = 0
                    # Check if landing on tile (falling)
                    elif self.vel_y >= 0:
                        dy = tile[1].top - self.rect.bottom
                        self.vel_y = 0
                        # Make sure player can only jump once
                        self.in_air = False

            # Check for collision with enemies
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, bat_group, False):
                game_over = -1  # Value of -1 triggers game over

            # Check collision with doors
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, door_group, False):
                game_over = 1  # Value of 1 means player has completed level

            # update player coordinates
            self.rect.x += dx
            self.rect.y += dy

        elif game_over == -1:
            # Turn player into ghost
            self.image = self.dead_image
            # Make ghost float up
            if self.rect.y > 200:
                self.rect.y -= 5

        # Draw player to screen
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        # Draw rectangle
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), self.rect, 2)

        return game_over

    # Method to reset game
    def reset(self, x, y):
        # Right run animation list
        self.images_rightRun = []
        # Append all right run animation images to list
        self.images_rightRun.append(pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Warrior/Run/run1.png'))
        self.images_rightRun.append(pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Warrior/Run/run2.png'))
        self.images_rightRun.append(pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Warrior/Run/run3.png'))
        self.images_rightRun.append(pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Warrior/Run/run4.png'))
        self.images_rightRun.append(pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Warrior/Run/run5.png'))
        self.images_rightRun.append(pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Warrior/Run/run6.png'))
        self.images_rightRun.append(pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Warrior/Run/run7.png'))
        self.images_rightRun.append(pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Warrior/Run/run8.png'))

        # New transformed right run list
        self.transformed_rightRun = []
        for img in self.images_rightRun:
            self.transformed_rightRun.append(pygame.transform.scale(img, (60, 90)))

        # Left run animation list
        self.images_leftRun = []
        for img in self.transformed_rightRun:
            self.images_leftRun.append(pygame.transform.flip(img, True, False))

        # Set index and counter of lists to 0
        self.index = 0
        self.counter = 0  # Counter controls speed of animation

        # Load and scale ghost image
        self.dead_image = pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Ghost/ghost.png')
        self.dead_image = pygame.transform.scale(self.dead_image, (40, 60))

        # Statement to display current sprite animation on screen
        self.image = self.transformed_rightRun[self.index]

        # Create player rectangle
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Get x coordinate
        self.rect.x = x
        # Get y coordinate
        self.rect.y = y
        # Width and height for rectangle
        self.width = self.image.get_width()
        self.height = self.image.get_height()
        # Set velocity in y direction to 0
        self.vel_y = 0
        # Player jump
        self.jumped = False
        # Player direction
        self.direction = 0
        # Check if player is in air
        self.in_air = True


# Class for enemies
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Calling constructor from super class
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # Load and scale bat images
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Assets/Images/Sprites/Bat/Fly/fly2.png')
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (50, 40))
        # Flip bat image
        self.left_image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)
        # Create rectangle
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        # Variables for movement
        self.move_direction = 1
        self.move_counter = 0

    def update(self):
        # Move bats left and right
        self.rect.x += self.move_direction
        self.move_counter += 1
        if abs(self.move_counter) > 100:
            self.move_direction *= -1
            self.move_counter *= -1
            # Flip bat images
            if self.move_direction == -1:
                self.image = self.left_image
            if self.move_direction == 1:
                self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.left_image, True, False)
        # Draw bat rectangle to screen
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), self.rect, 2)


# Class for enemies
class Doors(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Calling constructor from super class
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # Load and scale door images
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Assets/Medieval Tileset/PNG/Objects/door4.png')
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (80, 100))
        # Create rectangle
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y


# Level 1 map
world_data1 = [
    [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
]

# Level 2 map
world_data2 = [
    [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
]

# Level 3 map
world_data3 = [
    [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
]

# Store level maps in list
levels = [
    world_data1,
    world_data2,
    world_data3,
]

# Load in level data and create world
if current_level_index <= total_levels:
    level = levels[current_level_index]
    world = World(level)

# Create instance of button class
restart_button = Button(screen_width // 2 - 50, screen_height // 2 + 100, restart_img)
play_button = Button(screen_width // 2 - 550, screen_height // 2 - 220, play_img)
exit_button = Button(screen_width // 2 - 550, screen_height // 2 + 50, exit_img)
controls_button = Button(screen_width // 2 + 150, screen_height // 2 - 220, controls_img)
settings_button = Button(screen_width // 2 + 150, screen_height // 2 + 50, settings_img)
menu_button = Button(screen_width // 2 - 50, screen_height // 2 + 100, menu_img)

# Create instance of player class
player = Player(100, 800)

# main game loop
run = True
while run:

    # Set internal clock
    clock.tick(fps)

    # Draw background to screen
    screen.blit(background_img, (0, 0))

    # Display buttons on main menu
    if main_menu:
        # If exit button is clicked, close game
        if exit_button.draw():
            run = False
            # If play button is clicked, start game
        if play_button.draw():
            main_menu = False
        controls_button.draw()
        settings_button.draw()

    else:

        # Draw levels to screen
        world.drawWorld()

        # if the player dies, stop updating bats
        if game_over == 0:
            bat_group.update()

        # Draw bats to screen
        bat_group.draw(screen)
        # Draw doors to screen
        door_group.draw(screen)

        # Draw player to screen and return game_over value
        game_over = player.updatePlayer(game_over)

        # if player dies, display restart button
        if game_over == -1:
            if restart_button.draw():
                # Send player back to level 1
                current_level_index = 0
                reset_level(current_level_index)
                game_over = 0

        # If player has completed level, move to next level
        if game_over == 1:
            current_level_index += 1
            if current_level_index <= total_levels:
                reset_level(current_level_index)
                game_over = 0
            else:
                # If player has completed final level, open main menu
                if menu_button.draw():
                    main_menu = True

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your main loop logic is run at each frame, so here, at each frame you run level 1, then if game over == 1 you run level2 etc, so everything is reset all the time. I think your problem is there.

You could define a state that would hold the current level and use this.
For example:

```py
levels= ( # store your levels in some convenient structure
  World(world_data1),
  World(world_data2),
  World(world_data2),
)
current_level_index = 0 # The level state, initalized with the index of the first level
game_over = 0
while True:
   level = levels[current_level_index] # use your state to get the level instead of naming it directly
   level.drawWorld()
   # whatever you need to do to update your level logic, move things etc
   if game_over == 1:
     # This just is a simplistic example implementation to illustrate a change of level
     current_level_index += 1
```

This is just a trivial example but you can try to structure your code in this kind of way.

Comment: I have implemented your ideas and many of the errors I was receiving are now solved, so thank you! However, the only issue I'm having is: I can't seem to get the first "world_data" that is loaded in to stop drawing to the screen (world_data1) and get the other 2 (world_data2 and world_data3) to actually draw to the screen. The doors and the bats are changing with each level, but the layout of tiles is not. Do you have an idea as to why this may be happening?

Comment: @Cammi Maybe you are not blitting you background tiles at each frames but only at initialization ? It's difficult for me to answer that without seeing your code, but it looks like something like that...

Comment: I have updated my original question above with my improved code. I think the problem you have suggested may be what is happening, I just can't pinpoint where exactly in my code I'm making that mistake. Would you possibly be able to take a look?

Comment: I'm looking at it..

Comment: I'm could run your code because I don't have the images, but I could see a pair or problems: I saw you stored in a list you tilemaps for each level, but you only instanciated you variable "world" once. I suggest you try something more like in the example I gave, instaciating each level, so each item of your levels list would be a World instance. Because, right now, if you change your state "current_level_index" the actual world instance is not refreshed.

Comment: @Cammi I also see you `reset_level` function returns a World instance, which is good, but you never use it.
When you call `reset_level(current_level_index)` at lines 545 and 552, try `world = reset_level(current_level_index)` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved all of my issues now. I really appreciate your help.